# How to debug VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST from calling vkCmdTraceRaysNV?

Tags: c++, vulkan, raytracing

I'm working on a vulkan ray tracing application and I'm kinda stuck. Everything seems to work up until I call vkCmdTraceRaysNV and record it into my command buffer, the application crashes with an exception in vkQueueSubmit returning VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. I have checked basic stuff in Nvidia NSight, textures seem correct and acceleration structures are visualized correctly. Standard validation layer gives nothing. I think its either something with the shader binding table or the contents of the command buffer executing in a weird order. Are there any other options for validation besides staring at code?

This is the content of the command buffer, maybe someone knows whatsup (if I comment vkCmdTraceRaysNV out it doesnt crash):

```
VkViewport viewport{};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = static_cast<float>(extent.width);
viewport.height = static_cast<float>(extent.height);
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

VkRect2D scissor{};
scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
scissor.extent = extent;

VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo{};
renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
renderPassInfo.framebuffer = framebuffers[framebufferIndex];
renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = extent;

std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
clearValues[0].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();

// begin normal vertex rendering
vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffer, &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline);

VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
VkDeviceSize offset[] = { 0 };

vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offset);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VkPipelineBindPoint::VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);

for (const auto& object : objects) {
    vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4), &object.model);
    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(object.indices.size()), 1, object.indexOffset, object.vertexOffset, 0);
}

vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffer);

// acquire textures for ray tracing use
ImageMemoryBarrier(cmdBuffer, depthTexture.image, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT, 
    0, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL);

ImageMemoryBarrier(cmdBuffer, shadowsTexture.image, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
    0, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL);

// bind the pipeline and resources
vkCmdBindPipeline(cmdBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_RAY_TRACING_NV, pipeline);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(cmdBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_RAY_TRACING_NV, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);
vkCmdPushConstants(cmdBuffer, pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_RAYGEN_BIT_NV, 0, sizeof(pushData), &pushData);

// calculate SBT
VkDeviceSize progSize = rtProps.shaderGroupBaseAlignment;  // Size of a program identifier
VkDeviceSize rayGenOffset   = 0u * progSize;  // Start at the beginning of m_sbtBuffer
VkDeviceSize missOffset     = 1u * progSize;  // Jump over raygen
VkDeviceSize missStride     = progSize;

// run ray tracing, this is where it crashes
vk_nv_ray_tracing::vkCmdTraceRaysNV(cmdBuffer, 
     sbtBuffer, rayGenOffset, // raygen group 
     sbtBuffer, missOffset, missStride, // miss group
     VK_NULL_HANDLE, 0, 0, 
     VK_NULL_HANDLE, 0, 0, 
     width, height, 1
);
```

Shader Binding Table code:

```
/// define the groups, a miss group and raygen group
VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoNV group = {};
group.generalShader         = 0;
group.anyHitShader          = VK_SHADER_UNUSED_NV;
group.closestHitShader      = VK_SHADER_UNUSED_NV;
group.intersectionShader    = VK_SHADER_UNUSED_NV;
group.sType                 = VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_GROUP_CREATE_INFO_NV;
group.type                  = VkRayTracingShaderGroupTypeNV::VK_RAY_TRACING_SHADER_GROUP_TYPE_GENERAL_NV;

groups.push_back(group);
group.generalShader = 1;
groups.push_back(group);

const uint32_t groupCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(groups.size());
const uint32_t sbtSize = groupCount * rtProps.shaderGroupBaseAlignment;
std::vector<uint8_t> shaderHandles(sbtSize);

if (vk_nv_ray_tracing::vkGetRayTracingShaderGroupHandlesNV(device, pipeline, 0, groupCount, sbtSize, shaderHandles.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to get rt shader group handles");
    }

VkBufferCreateInfo sbtBufferCreateInfo = {};
sbtBufferCreateInfo.size = sbtSize;
sbtBufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
sbtBufferCreateInfo.sType = VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
sbtBufferCreateInfo.usage = VkBufferUsageFlagBits::VK_BUFFER_USAGE_RAY_TRACING_BIT_NV;

VmaAllocationCreateInfo sbtBufferAllocInfo = {};
sbtBufferAllocInfo.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_TO_GPU;
sbtBufferAllocInfo.flags = VmaAllocationCreateFlagBits::VMA_ALLOCATION_CREATE_MAPPED_BIT;

VmaAllocationInfo allocInfo{};

if (vmaCreateBuffer(allocator, &sbtBufferCreateInfo, &sbtBufferAllocInfo, &sbtBuffer, &sbtAlloc, &allocInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create sbt buffer");
}

auto* pData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(allocInfo.pMappedData);
for (uint32_t g = 0; g < groupCount; g++) {
    std::memcpy(pData, groups.data() + g * rtProps.shaderGroupHandleSize, rtProps.shaderGroupHandleSize);
    pData += rtProps.shaderGroupBaseAlignment;
}
```

Comment: From my experience, crashes at command buffer submission when using RT often point to a problem with the acceleration structure setup. E.g. using wrong memory types for scratch buffers, freeing memory too early, etc. So it would

Comment: @SaschaWillems The Vulkan overlord himself! :D Both bottom and top level acceleration structures visualize correctly in NSight (it's just a single cube) with deep copying disabled so I assume they're fine?

Comment: I'd still check proper usage bits, esp. for the scratch buffers. If you can rule out the AS, then check your shader binding table, and make sure you have copied the proper shader handles from the pipeline to the SBT.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Even though I didn't create the acceleration structure and I didn't bind data, it still returns VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST and VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT was reported in VK_NV_device_diagnostic_checkpoints

In my case, there was a problem with the size of the shader binding table and how it was copied.

Comment: I'll definitely checkout that VK_NV_device_diagnostic_checkpoints extension for debugging, thanks! I'll also add the SBT code to the post, maybe there's some glaring issue.